# Find minimum value between two functions and print it

Tags: r

I have this code below:

```
immediate.amput.EV <- function() 

  {

    return((Dead.prob * Dead.cost) + (Alive.prob * Alive.cost))
  }     


immediate.amput.EV()

watchful.EV <- function()
  {
  progression.cost <- (progression.dead.prob * progression.dead.cost) + 
                      (progression.alive.prob * progression.alive.cost)
  return((cure.prob * cure.cost) + (progression.prob * progression.cost))
}     


watchful.EV()
```

Both of them return numbers.
I need to find the minimum of this numbers and print that out... i mean which function has the smallest cost...

Would be grateful if you can help me..
Thanks..

Comment: `min(watchful.EV(),immediate.amput.EV())`?

Comment: That was great, could please post it as an answer so i can accept it?
Ah, and, please, could you tell me how to print something like: The function with the smallest cost is:

Comment: Done. However, I would recommend you search a little more, this should have been easily google-able.

Comment: Just to confirm, you mean the minimum **of** two functions, not the minimum (distance) between two functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste("The function with the smallest cost is",min(watchful.EV(),immediate.amput.EV()))
```